# Download and injecting unity scene in runtime

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

It's possible that we start an android project in which it's necessary after recognising an image by camera to visualise a content generated in unity.

The easy part would be to use webGL to display it, but there is the problem of devices that do not support it directly. My question is if from android (and later iOs). It's possible to download a content of unity, load and visualise it in runtime?.
Is possible that I had to direct all the effort to generate that content in a .jar and then use something like dependency injection to load it?

I have already a unity scene in an activity but of course in project definition not in run time.

Any help or guidance would be welcome.

Comment: consider a dynamic scene with downloadable levels made with json object and level generator instead.

Answer (score -2):

Unity builds levels into the final runtime executable, so adding a downloaded 'scene' directly is not possible. The best way around this is to create a 'generator' scene which can accept input from a downloaded text file, such as JSON, and use that to render the level.

However, this method does assume that all the possible objects that can be rendered are in your game as prefabs. If you're wanting to pull images from the net to be loaded into textures, the WWW class might get you started down the right path:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture.html

Comment: The main functionality of the app is a unity content viewer. These contents are different every time and unknown to me, so initially each one would have their prefabs, textures and scripts surely (I think scripts are not possible to load them in execution).

My alternative was in android to download an apk with the game of unity, but I'm sure the appStore / ios will not let me do something similar.